# Fiber#alive? not defined

Tags: ruby, fiber

I use ruby1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) i686-linux. `Fiber#alive?` returns an undefined error:

```
fiber = Fiber.new{puts 'hello'}
fiber.alive?
=> undefined error
```

Other methods, for example, `Fiber#resume` , `Fiber.yield` seem to be working fine. What is wrong?

By the way, what is the difference between `Fiber#resume` and `Fiber#transfer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to `require 'fiber'` first:

```
f = Fiber.new { puts 'hello' }
  => #<Fiber:0x896109c> 

f.alive?
  # NoMethodError: undefined method `alive?' for #<Fiber:0x896109c>
  #      from (irb):2
  #      from /home/johnf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc1/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'

require 'fiber'
  => true 

f.alive?
  => true
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't forget it, I didn't know it. It didn't say so in the doc. Its says you need to do that for `Fiber.current`, but it doesn't say so for `Fiber#alive?`.

Comment: Probably a documentation oversight, then. When in doubt, read the code. :)

Comment: So requiring fiber is only required for some, not all of Fiber's methods?

Comment: @Andrew That seems to be the case. As far as I checked on my irb, `.new`, `.yield`, `#resume` don't require `require`. `.current`, `#alive?`, `#transfer` do.